# Fast search all triangles (3D space) that are intersected by a specified Z plane

Tags: c#, 3d, geometry, intersection, plane

I have a complex 3D object all made of triangles(more than 1.000.000 triangles). I need to get (very fast) all triangles that are intersected by a specified Z plane. 
For example there are 2 triangles

```
T1 = P1(0,0,0) P2(0,0,10) P3(0,10, 0)
T2 = P1(50,50,50) P2(50,50,60) P3(50,60,50)
Z plane = 3
```

in this example T1 is intersected by Z=3 , T2 not.
My big problem is to know what is the best structure tu use to store triangles (KD-Tree, AABB ...) and how to efficiently search only the triangles that have TZmin > Z > TZmax.
I have to do all in C# and I'm very new to this type of 3D problems.
Every help is very appreciated.

By GMG

Comment: Well, I wouldn't know about the "best" way, but KD-Trees are quite alright for this kind of tasks. Also, I would consider delegating computations to the GPU, as it is designed to do this piece of work. XNA and SharpDX are good starting point for that. But as always: before worrying about speed you should actually check if it is too slow...

Comment: What I want to know is what is the best approach, and very fast is what algorithm give me the minor time to do the selection job. A "for cile" for all triangles is a very slow approach for example